# Show that if $L$ is recursively enumerable (RE) then $L$ is the domain of some partial computable function

Tags: computer-science, computability

> Show that if $L$ is recursively enumerable (RE) then $L$ is the domain
>   of some partial computable function

I know that what it does mean recursively enumerable, but I don't what it does mean `domain of some partial computable function`.
So, not only I can't prove it, I even don't know what to prove.
I tried to solve similar tasks, but no effect.

Can you help me, please? I ask for explanation for dummy.

**Edit**

So, lets try to construct function $f: L\to \{0,1\}$ where

$$f(w \not \in L) = 0 \text{iff Turing machine rejects $w$} 
f(w\in L) = 1 \text{iff Turing machine accepts $w$}$$

it should ends proof.

Comment: A partial function - computable or otherwise - is a function from some *subset* (possibly proper) of $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$; that is, it's not quite a function $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, since its domain is maybe not all of $\mathbb{N}$. For example, consider the function $f(x)$ given by $f(x)=17$ if $x$ is even and $f(x)$ is undefined otherwise. Then this is a partial function, and its domain is the set of even numbers. Now that $f$ happens to be computable (exercise), so we now know: *the set of even numbers is the domain of some partial computable function* (namely, $f$).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I edited, can you look again ?

Comment: Relevant: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/31981/what-is-a-partially-computable-function.

Answer (score 0):

Fix some algorithm (Turing machine/computer program in some Turing-complete language...). For any given input, the algorithm can:

(a) Run for some finite time and give a result.

OR

(b) Run forever.

This gives a *partial computable function*: is defined and *computable* for some inputs (case a) and undefined for other inputs (case b).

EDIT:

Let be $A$ the [algorithm than enumerates the members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_set) of $L$. We can define another algorithm by "running $A$ in parallel":

Do the first step of $A(1)$;

Do the second step of $A(1)$;

Do the first step of $A(2)$;

Do the third step of $A(1)$;

Do the second step of $A(2)$;

Do the first step of $A(3)$;

$\cdots$

If $A(n)$ stops, define $f(n) = 1$. If $A(n)$ runs forever, $f(n)$ is undefined.

Comment: @Marin, I edited. Can you check my reasoning ?

Comment: @HaskellFun, "reject" and "accept" usually means that the Turing machine ends in *both* cases (http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3554/what-is-the-difference-between-halting-accepting-and-deciding-in-the-context-o). Is valid... but actually a *total* function: defined for *all* the inputs.

Comment: So my solution is ok or not ?

Comment: @HaskellFun, the example is a partial computable function because total $\implies$ partial. But isn't an answer to the question "Show that if $L$ is recursively enumerable (RE) then $L$ is the domain of some partial computable function". Ask again if you can't prove this.

Comment: Ok, I can't prove it, show me please

Comment: @HaskellFun, I can't do now. Tomorrow will edit my answer. Idea: start from algorithm that generates the set $L$.

Comment: ok I wait unil tomorrow